# How do I fix the error code P2002 which is caused by filter or sensor in the exhaust of the car?

Tags: car, exhaust, sensor, oil-filter, air-filter

Do anyone know that how to fix this code?

Comment: Which vehicle and what year?

Comment: Please read thru the [help] to better understand how this site works. You should not be posting extremely vague hypothetical questions for the purpose of writing your own generic answer. This site is for *specific* questions about problems you actually are dealing with.

Comment: I would like to remind everyone, that while a more fleshed out question is probably warranted, answering your own questions is completely fine on the site. Stack Exchange encourages users to answer their own questions.

Comment: But then should we expect answers that actually have the most common solution : ie "give the vehicle a good run" in this particular case which the OP has not managed to mention?

Comment: These answers by PARTS AVATAR-CANADA seem to be exact duplicates of answers posted in Quora. Not sure if this is a good or a bad thing. Not a copyright violation (assuming the poster is the copyright holder), not duplicate content on the same site... But I still believe the original source should be specified, as it could otherwise be considered self-plagiarism.

Comment: @juhist - Agreed; it should be annotated by the OP.

Comment: @SolarMike - As always, if you have a better answer or solution post it as an answer. Just because the user self-answers doesn't mean their solution is better or even correct.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I posted it as a comment to his answer - perhaps hoping that the answer would be improved, but it may happen when it gets referenced...

Answer (score 0):

**DEFINITION OF P2002 ERROR CODE:**

This error code is diesel-specific OBD-II code, which means it applies to most vehicles equipped diesel engines. Error Code P2002 is defined as Diesel Particulate Filter Efficiency below Threshold Bank 1, which refers to an issue in the efficiency of the particulate filter in the exhaust, which is most likely caused by faulty filter or sensor, or exhaust leak.

Specifications on the definition, troubleshooting, and repairs, of course, vary from one make and model to another.

Diesel engines usually offer better torque and fuel economy than gasoline engines. However, the diesel fuel itself produces more “soot” which is considered hazardous to both the atmosphere and human health. Modern diesel engine technology and fuel, on the other hand, has been refined to eliminate many of these emissions. There are, of course, still some circumstances when more soot is generated. This usually happens when the engine is not running hot, such as in stop-and-go traffic and short trips.

To capture these PM emissions, a Diesel Particulate Filter (DPF) is included in diesel engine vehicles. They’re collected during low-load conditions.

**COMMON SYMPTOMS:**

In many cases, there may not be any observable symptoms other than the Check Engine lights, but for some vehicles, the PCM may put the vehicle on ‘Limp Mode,’ which restricts both the performance of the engine and the transmission. Other vehicles with overcharged DPG may show other symptoms like:
1. Hard starting
2. Poor acceleration
3. Poor fuel economy

**HOW TO CHECK:**

To diagnose this code, conduct a visual inspection of both the particulate filter and the back pressure sensor and associated wirings.

After checking those components, take the vehicle for a test drive with an OBD-II scanner connected to track the back pressure sensor readings. It would be best to have your mechanic with you for these diagnosis steps.

If Bank 1 seems to be sending mixed signals than the Bank 2, then your mechanic will conduct further troubleshooting of the sensor to determine whether the particulate sensor must be replaced.

**HOW TO FIX:**

1. The most common solution for this code is to manually put the vehicle on the DPF regen mode by using a scan tool or taking the vehicle out on the highway for a little longer to let the heat burn off the stored PM emissions.
2. Clearing the diesel particulate filter
3. Changing diesel fuel
4. Replacement of the particulate filter
5. Replacement of DPS
6. Diesel particulate filters were first used in the mid-2000s. If your vehicle is older, then there’s a good chance it doesn’t come with this component and you will not encounter this error code.

Comment: Give the vehicle a good drive at least once or twice a month - get it up to temperature and sufficient distance and it won't be an issue....